# iText PDFXFA library: Issue with some of the fields while flattening using flattenXDP( )

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, itext7, xfa

I'm trying to flatten the XFA PDF using iText pdfxfa library. On flattening the pdf using the demo application provided by iText, I get all the data correctly embedded in my pdf. But when I try to do it using my code, it is otherwise. The data for the text fields, checkboxes gets correctly embedded, but for attachment names. By 'attachments' I'm referring to: The dynamic form can contain another PDF(attachment) inside it. The 'attachment' can be added to the PDF using buttons provided in the XFA pdf. Below is the code I'm using to flatten the PDF. I've copied the XFA of the PDF using iText RUPS in a separate file and used it as `InputStream` to XFA `flattenXDP()`.

```
private void flattenXFA(String flattenedPDFDest) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(flattenedPDFDest);
    XFAFlattener xfaf = new XFAFlattener();
    // The XFA for the PDF is copied from iText RUPS in the phshuman10.xfa.xml file.
    xfaf.flattenXDP(new FileInputStream("/home/NetBeansProjects/kitext/resources/phshuman10.xfa.xml"), fos);
    fos.close();
}
```

Link to the zip of all required PDF's:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6w278NcMSCrT2p6cWQxZG0yYVU/view?usp=sharing

The name of PDF in the zip:

1. Flattened PDF using itext demo: checkResult.pdf
2. Sample filled copy of form: PHSHumanSubjectsAndClinicalTrialsInfo-V1.0 (10).pdf
3. Flattened PDF using my code: tt_flattened3.pdf
4. The XFA file for PHSHumanSubjectsAndClinicalTrialsInfo-V1.0 (10).pdf: phshuman10.xfa.xml

If required, my scenario can be adequately reproduced using the uploaded resources! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. If you open your original XFA form as a PDF file in a PDF Viewer, you will be able to see that there are 4 attachments in this PDF file. XFA itself is an XML-based format which can be embedded into PDF, and it can actually interconnect with PDF file by some JavaScript APIs.

What happens is that in your form the JavaScript code in your XFA form communicates with PDF file (most likely by proprietary Acrobat's API), and is able to retrieve the attachments.

When you try to flatten pure XDP package, you only extract the XML from PDF that is responsible for definition of XFA form, some datasets etc, but do not extract anything related to PDF file itself: fonts, images, attachments.

In case XFA form uses some PDF resources, you will not be able to flatten them 100% correctly as in original form contained in PDF.

Thus, if PDF resources are used in XFA form, you will have to flatten the PDF form directly via `flatten(InputStream, OutputStream)` method, which accepts the input stream for a PDF containing an XFA form, and output stream for the resultant flattened PDF file.